# Proving complex series convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

How can I prove that the complex series converges where $w,z \in \mathbb{C}$ with $w\ne0$: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{wz^n} = \frac{w}{1-z} \iff |z|<1$$

It seems it can be treated like a (real) geometric series. Is the $|z|<1$ condition for convergence equivalent to both $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\Re(z^n)}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\Im(z^n)}$ converging? Does that help prove the above fact?

Comment: The equivalence is false. If $w=0$, then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty wz^n=\frac w{1-z}$ for *every* $z\in\Bbb C\setminus\{1\}$.

Comment: The condition $|z| < 1$ is becuase if we use polar coordinates $z=r e^{i \theta}$ then $z^n = r^n e^{i n \theta}$ and $|z|=r$, i.e. if the module is less than $1$ then, $z^n$ convergees to $0 \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: That thing with the real and imaginary parts does not help prove the equivalence, it makes it more complicated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula for the partial sums (when $z\ne1$)
$$
\sum_{n=0}^N wz^n = \frac{w(1-z^{N+1})}{1-z}
$$
works perfectly well for complex numbers (it's just an algebraic verification). Since $\sum_{n=0}^\infty wz^n$ converges if and only if $\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^N wz^n$ exists by definition, we are reduced to considering
$$
\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^N wz^n = \lim_{N\to \infty}\frac{w(1-z^{N+1})}{1-z} = \frac{w}{1-z}\bigl(1- \lim\limits_{N\to \infty} z^{N+1} \bigr);
$$
and the limit on the right-hand side exists if and only if $|z|<1$ (when $z\ne1$), where it equals $0$.

Comment: To be really precise we should probably make cases $z=1$ and $w=0$ on their own:  if $z = 1$ then the infinite sum $\sum_0^\infty w$ converges if and only if $w=0$.  If $w=0$ the infinite sum converges $\sum_0^\infty 0z^n$ to $0$ for all values of $z$.